# What if a block size limit in a certain blockchain is exceeded and a new block isn't yet created?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

What if a block size limit in the Bitcoin blockchain or any other blockchain is exceeded and at that time a new block isn't yet mined? I have been thinking about this lately and I haven't found any article pertaining to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. If no new block is ever created, then no new block is ever created. A blockchain that does not grow won't ever add new data. (Remember that blocks can be added without creating bitcoin; they just can't be added without adding a block.) In any case, you'll want to move this question to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com. It's not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the context of bitcoin ,
you are missing mempoolsize with block size,
transactions are stored in mempool which acts as a (pool obviously), miners take transactions out of the pool and put it in a block and try to ming it(find a Nounce for it)
so.

if a new block is not mined the new transactions are piling up in the mempool, miners may let the mempool to grow for a while but at somepoint they will not have the resources and would be forced to reject new transactions.

this will have a negative effect on the network, would drive down the price and disinsetivise miners to try more... slowly blockchain would die...
unless a hard fork happens

Comment: Thank you I did not know about the mempool. Thank you very much for answering my question.